# Need help identifying what looks to be a skull

Tags: species-identification, zoology, marine-biology

[image: bony structure on white background]  ( BOTTOM VIEW )I was given this skull(?) by someone a few years ago, it was found washed up on a beach in Panama. I collect bones so usually I’m really good at IDing skulls and I’ve spent some time trying to just generally research skulls that look the same. I’ve looked at snake, fish, mammal, and bird skulls but none of them seem to match, it’s just a very odd shape. I researched on animals that live in the water in Panama but none of them matched up. I could just not be looking hard enough or looking at the wrong things. It doesn’t have a lower jaw and the eye sockets or at least I think they are, are very deep inside the skull. It does seem to have a base for vertebrae. Which is why I assume it’s a skull along with the general structure. The top part of the piece is completely flat with a small incline.

This is my first question so please tell me if I’m missing anything.

Comment: I don’t know if it’s just my view of the app, but I don’t see a photo of the specimen, which would be helpful. Could you upload one? Thanks!

Comment: I apologize I forgot to add the images I’m so sorry

Comment: Im having a problem with my post, It won’t let me paste the pictures I wanted to add. I’m sorry for any inconvenience I thought they were part of the post.

Comment: @Jacob You might try from desktop if you are using a phone. Or if a phone is the only option, at least use the browser version and not an app.

Comment: thank you! using the desktop version worked.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please [edit] your post to include the size and if possible pictures from other angles. Thanks! 

Comment: Probably not a skull. It's probably part of a bird's synsacrum